# WCF service instance and concurrency set to single, but new instances created occasionally?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted by IIS that requires:

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

This is done because it is calling some very old legacy code that does not play well with threading whatsoever.

Occasionally, we are seeing cases in our logs where the same IIS worker process will create a new instance of the service object. What type of situations can cause this to happen, and is there any way to prevent this?  The service is basically hosed at this point, so right now I am considering killing the process when I detect a problem.

The servers in question are not under heavy load at all - lots of available memory and CPU, and Maximum of 3 worker processes in the Application Pool. The processes keep busy enough they don't idle timeout.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Perhaps when the application pool is recycled by IIS?

Comment: Well the specific worker process stays up and running, so I don't think the pool is being recycled in these cases.